# Ignore duplicate values in PHP - MYSQL using Arraymap

Tags: php, sql, arrays, array-map

DB

```
Date        Price  qty
2012-10-21  $11 150
2012-10-22  $12 90
2012-10-22  $12 10
2012-10-23  $13 250
```

CODE

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY 'date'");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $orders[] = array(
            'Date' => $row['date'],
            'price' => $row['price'],
            'Quantity' => $row['qty']
        );
    }
```

I don't need to get duplicate dates and for those duplicate dates need to get Average `price` and sum of `Qty` like below example:

EXAMPLE

```
Date        Price  qty
2012-10-21  $11 150
2012-10-22  $12 100
2012-10-23  $13 250
```

I try to use `Array-map` but i fail on that help is really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to move the problem to the database by using this query using `GROUP BY` and the respective [aggregation functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html):

```
SELECT `date`, AVG( `price` ), SUM( `qty`)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `date`
```

In general, it is more advisable to let MySQL do such work, than first transmitting the data to your application and rearrange it there.

Comment: thats not bad.. anyway thanx

Answer (score 0):

Change you query

```
SELECT Date, AVG(Price), SUM(Qty) FROM table
GROUP BY Date
```

Or change php to check if date in array and calculate averages and sums

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
   $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT date, AVG(Price) as price, SUM(qty) FROM table GROUP BY date ORDER BY date");

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $orders[] = array(
        'Date' => $row['date'],
        'price' => $row['price'],
        'Quantity' => $row['qty']
     );
   }
```